# Write output of the local command into the file in the running docker container

Tags: linux, bash, docker

I have file template which has various variables. I would like to constitute these variables with values before I copy this file to
**running** container. This what I do right now:

```sh
export $(grep -v '^#' /home/user/.env | xargs) && \
    envsubst < template.yaml > new_connection.yaml && \
    docker cp new_connection.yaml docker_container:/app && \
    rm new_connection.yaml
```

This is working, however I'm sure there is a way I can skip file creation/copy/remove steps and do just something like: `echo SOME_TEXT > new_connection.yaml` straight to the container. Could you help?

Comment: You can do that with a process substitution `docker cp <(envsubst < template.yaml) docker_container:/app` but then you'll loose the information about `envsubst` succeeding or not.

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't use a Dockerfile for this? I would create a Dockerfile, add the extra commands, build the container, and then use the newly created container instead.

Another option is to add an entrypoint.sh script that does the envsubst for you based on env vars when the container starts.

Comment: @seldesjo I would like to do that on already running container

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a good application for an *entrypoint wrapper script*.  If your image has both an `ENTRYPOINT` and a `CMD`, then [Docker passes the `CMD` as additional arguments to the `ENTRYPOINT`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-cmd-and-entrypoint-interact).  That makes it possible to write a simple script that rewrites the configuration file, then runs the `CMD`:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
envsubst < template.yaml > /app/new_connection.yaml
exec "$@"
```

In the Dockerfile, `COPY` the script in and make it the `ENTRYPOINT`.  (If your host system doesn't correctly preserve executable file permissions or Unix line endings you may need to do some additional fixups in the Dockerfile as well.)

```sh
COPY entrypoint.sh ./
ENTRYPOINT ["/app/entrypoint.sh"]  # must be JSON-array form
CMD same command as the original image
```

When you run the container, you need to pass in the environment file, but there's a built-in option for this

```sh
docker run --env-file /home/user/.env ... my-image
```

If you want to see this working, any command you provide after the image name replaces the Dockerfile `CMD`, but it will still be passed to the `ENTRYPOINT` as arguments.  So you can, for example, see the rewritten config file in a new temporary container:

```sh
docker run --rm --env-file /home/user/.env my-image \
  cat /app/new_connection.yaml
```

Comment: thanks, I modified the question. I want to run some commands on already running container, so there is no more Dockerfile anymore

Comment: Programs will frequently only read their configuration files once on startup.  In that very common case you'd have to stop and restart the main container process to re-read the configuration, and therefore delete and recreate the container.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, I agree with David Maze and the comment section. You should probably build your image in such a way that it picks up env vars on startup and uses them accordingly.

---

However, to answer your question, you can pipe the output of `envsubst` to the running container.

```sh
$ echo 'myVar: ${FOO}' > env.yaml
$ FOO=bar envsubst < env.yaml | docker run -i busybox cat
myVar: bar
```

If you want to write that to a file, using redirection, you need to wrap it in a `sh -c` because otherwise the redirection is treated as redirect the container output to some path on the host.

```sh
FOO=bar envsubst < env.yaml | docker run -i busybox sh -c 'cat > my-file.yaml'
```

I did it here with `docker run` but you can do the same with `exec`.

```
FOO=bar envsubst < env.yaml | docker exec -i <container> cat
```